# How to built multiClass classifier using cnn and sparse_Categorical_Crossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am a beginner in machine learning and working on a **Multiclass classification** problem where i am predicting the three categories of animals cat , dog and horse and using value as follows (dog=0 ,cat=1, horse=2). I was doing it with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and got 95% accuracy but at prediction my model gives 3 different results. So, is anything wrong with the code or am doing it wrongly?
here is my whole code with output:

```
# load dogs vs cats vs horse dataset, reshape and save to a new file
from os import listdir
from numpy import asarray
from numpy import save
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
# define location of dataset
folder = 'train/'
photos, labels = list(), list()
# enumerate files in the directory
for file in listdir(folder):
    # determine class
    output = 0.0
    if file.startswith('cat'):
        output = 1.0
    if file.startswith('horse'):
        output = 2.0
    # load image
    photo = load_img(folder + file, target_size=(200, 200))
    # convert to numpy array
    photo = img_to_array(photo)
    # store
    photos.append(photo)
    labels.append(output)
# convert to a numpy arrays
photos = asarray(photos)
labels = asarray(labels)
print(photos.shape, labels.shape)
# save the reshaped photos
save('animals_photos.npy', photos)
save('animals_labels.npy', labels)
```

**output: (600, 200, 200, 3) (600,)**

Here is my model code:

```
# save the final model to file
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# define cnn model
def define_model():
    # load model
    model = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

    # mark loaded layers as not trainable
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    # add new classifier layers
    flat1 = Flatten()(model.layers[-1].output)
    class1 = Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(flat1)
    output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(class1)
    # define new model
    model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=output)  
    # compile model
    opt = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# run the test harness for evaluating a model
def run_test_harness():
# define model
    model = define_model()
    # create data generator
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True)
    # specify imagenet mean values for centering
    datagen.mean = [123.68, 116.779, 103.939]
    # prepare iterator
    train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset_animal/',
        class_mode='sparse', batch_size=64, target_size=(224, 224))
    # fit model
    model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=len(train_it), epochs=10, verbose=1)
    # save model
    model.save('animal_model_sparse.h5')

# entry point, run the test harness
run_test_harness()
```

Below code is predicting the image with model:

```
# make a prediction for a new image.
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model
from numpy import argmax
# load and prepare the image
def load_image(filename):
    # load the image
    img = load_img(filename, target_size=(224, 224))
    # convert to array
    img = img_to_array(img)
    # reshape into a single sample with 3 channels
    img = img.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)
    # center pixel data
    img = img.astype('float32')
    img = img - [123.68, 116.779, 103.939]
    return img

# load an image and predict the class
def run_example():
    # load the image
    img = load_image('train\horse.90.jpg')
    # load model
    model = load_model('animal_model_sparse.h5')
    # predict the class
    result = model.predict(img)
    print(result[0])

# entry point, run the example
run_example()
```

**Output:**

```
[0.4865459  0.35041294 0.16304109]
```

Comment: For the example output prediction, your model has predicted 0.4865459 probability that the image is in category 0 (dog), 0.35041294 probability of 1 (cat) and 0.16304109 probability of 2 (horse).

Comment: Ok can you provide the dataset what you trainde against and the horse image?

Comment: I have used argmax but then output result is either 0 or 1 not 2. can you suggest any improvement then please let me know. should i use only categorical cross entropy for this problem or not.

Comment: What is your validation accuracy ?

Comment: What dataset you used?

Comment: The horse image was the part of the traning or validation set?

Comment: #Samer Ayoub My validation accuracy was also somehow same as training accuracy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provided the info I requested, but I followed the code and it simply worked well:

```
# make a prediction for a new image.
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model
from numpy import argmax
# load and prepare the image
def load_image(filename):
    # load the image
    img = load_img(filename, target_size=(224, 224))
    # convert to array
    img = img_to_array(img)
    # reshape into a single sample with 3 channels
    img = img.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)
    # center pixel data
    img = img.astype('float32')
    img = img - [123.68, 116.779, 103.939]
    return img

# load an image and predict the class
def run_example():
    # load the image
    img = load_image('D:/___COMMON/Project/Test_area/VGG16-classifier_animals/train/horse-90.jpg')
    # load model    
    model = load_model('animal_model_sparse.h5')
    # predict the class
    result = model.predict(img)
    print(result[0])

# entry point, run the example
run_example()
```

**Out:**

```
[0. 0. 1.]
```

So if you want to better inspections, please provide more information and feedbacks.

Comment: SOrry i was not able to answer because i was busy in some other work well i was using the image for prediction was part of training set and amm using dataset from kaggle

Comment: looks like you have used one hot encoding in building the model can you show me how you have achieved this.

Comment: @AbdulWahab No I didn't use one-hot encoding, I used your code. These values is the result of it, what is the softmax output of your model. The model is 100% sure, that it is a horse, as it is overfitted on the trained data.

Comment: but now i am using 2600 images per category still at prediction am getting values in something like 5.5e-7 like this

Comment: for some reason i cant write whole output. Here are the results of my training and testing accuracy.
Found 5827 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 1973 images belonging to 3 classes.

Epoch 10/10
92/92 [==============================] - 213s 2s/step - loss: 4.1547e-04 - accuracy: 0.9998 - val_loss: 0.0223 - val_accuracy: 0.9726
31/31 [==============================] - 54s 2s/step
> 97.263

Comment: @AbdulWahab 606 images,  5.5e-7 is actually 0, so the class prediction close to 1, which matters.

Comment: but when my code saves results to the animal_model.h5 file then it drops accuracy  to 87% here are the results.
Found 7800 images belonging to 2 classes.

Epoch 10/10
122/122 [==============================] - 213s 2s/step - loss: 0.3437 - accuracy: 0.8685

Comment: and here is my models prediction. Output:
[5.5598584e-03 9.9444020e-01 3.3587802e-27]

Comment: can you help me to sort this out.

Comment: @AbdulWahab You wrote  "it drops accuracy to 87% here are the results. Found 7800 images belonging to 2 classes." First here is only 2 classes, second did you retrain your model here?

Comment: then why its getting only two classes i am not able to understand this thing and yes i am training my model here and just saving it to model file

Comment: Thanks for helping out I have an issue with my path which i had given Thumbs up :)

Comment: @AbdulWahab If you want to solve your issue I'll gadly help you rolling up till its end. Just confirm if you are still on it, after a few hours I will back again.